# Simple function won't return array value based on variable

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Quick and short question. The code below is just the way I want it to be. For some reason, however, it doesn't work. No errors are shown (error_reporting is -1) and nothing happens.

```
<?php
    $data_clean_type = 'numeric';

    $data_clean_filter = array('alpha' => '/^[a-zA-Z]*$/', 'numeric' => '/^[0-9]*$/', 'alphanumeric' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/');

    if(in_array($data_clean_type, $data_clean_filter)) {
        echo $data_clean_filter[$data_clean_type];
    }
?>
```

I'm expecting to see the content of $data_clean_filter['numeric'] (reg exp for numeric), but nothing happens. I'm no novice, but I can't see any mistakes in this code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `isset()`

`if(isset($data_clean_filter[$data_clean_type])) {`

You could also use `array_key_exists()`

`if(array_key_exists($data_clean_type, $data_clean_filter)){`

Comment: @Chris, please accept the answer then, don't leave it hanging ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking after the value, while you should be looking for the key:

```
if(in_array($data_clean_type,array_keys($data_clean_filter)))
```

As mentioned, you should rather use `isset`.

Comment: What the hell is this, use `isset`.

Comment: It's an explanation of why it do not work as he expect.

Answer (score -1):

thanks for the tips, it works now. the problem was that in_array checks the array's values, not the keys!

isset() is one way to do it, for this particular case I prefer array_key_exists().

```
<?php
    $data_clean_type = 'alpha';

    $data_clean_filter = array('alpha' => '/^[a-zA-Z]*$/', 'numeric' => '/^[0-9]*$/', 'alphanumeric' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/');

    if(array_key_exists($data_clean_type, $data_clean_filter)) {
        echo $data_clean_filter[$data_clean_type];
    }
?>
```